# Batch file for automatically deleting specified folders from within tree

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rmdir

I am trying to write a simple tool to delete junk Mac files from a Windows system, however, I am having trouble as a specified folder (.fseventsd) remains, no mater what I do. Below is the batch file, and the specific area of concern is the rmdir command in the :.fseventsd section.

```
rem @echo off
cls
cd \

:.fseventsd
echo Searching for '.fseventsd' folders.
rmdir /S /Q ".fseventsd" 2> nul
if errorlevel 1 echo No '.fseventsd' folders were found.
goto :.DS_STORE
if errorlevel 0 echo All '.fseventsd' folders have been deleted.

:.DS_STORE
echo.
echo Searching for '.DS_STORE' files.
del /s /q /f /a:rash .DS_STORE 2> nul
if errorlevel 1 echo No '.DS_STORE' files were found.
goto ._.*
if errorlevel 0 echo All '.DS_STORE' files have been deleted.

:._.*
echo.
echo Searching for '._.*' files.
del /s /q /f /a:rash ._.* 2> nul
if errorlevel 1 echo No '._.*' files were found.
goto END
if errorlevel 0 echo All '._.*' files have been deleted.
echo.

:END
echo All tasks have now been finished.
pause
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run `rmdir /S /Q ".fseventsd"` from the command prompt?

Comment: Is the folder local file space, or mounted+shared (presumably by both macOS and Windows)? That might affect your file access.

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Definitely Local

Comment: Are you expecting the `RMDIR` command to delete the folder if it is located in a sub folder of any folder within the directory tree?  If that is true then you need to do this differently.  The `RMDIR` command does not search for the directory you want to delete within the tree. It will only delete the folder from within the current working directory.

Comment: @Squashman Yep, that's exactly what I'm trying to do - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `for /r` loop which loops through subfolders just like this:

```
for /R "C:\path\you\want" %%A IN (.) do (
     if "%%A"=="Foldernameyouwant" rd Foldernameyouwant
```

You can make any minor changes you want to the code provided.

Hope this helps!